# How to iterate json dictionary in django template?

Tags: django, json, dictionary

I am new in django and now i am trying to iterate one json dictionary in html page. I am using the {{context}} for displaying the dictionary which is passed from the view and context is the variable used to store the dictionary in render_to_response. now it is diplayed like

```
[
  {
    "pk": 5, 
    "model": "Auction.newauction", 
    "fields": {
      "username": 1, 
      "category": "furniture", 
      "description": "Made of Wood", 
      "end_date": "2012-05-01 11:00:00", 
      "start_price": "100", 
      "title": "Table", 
      "start_date": "2012-03-04 11:24:11"
    }
  }
]
```

How I can iterate this dictionary to display like

```
username  : 1
category  : Furniture
```

Can anyone please help me

Comment: Why are you using a json object in your template? You should be able to pass it a Django model object from your view code. In your template you should then be able to do something like <p>Username: {{ auction.username }}<br />Category: {{ auction.category }}</p>. What do you have in your view code?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't "convert it to JSON" unless you're planning to have your logic in Javascript.  Instead, in your template you could iterate over the array in a `for` loop and traverse the dictionary to the username and category keys:

```
{% for c in context %}
  <div>username: {{ c.fields.username }}</div>
  <div>category: {{ c.fields.category }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```